# Sorting Date column in the UITable view in xcode

Tags: xcode, uitableview

I am having a table containing columns like name and date of birth. The data is coming from web service. What i want to do is to sort the rows depending on date of birth. means the younger one should be the first person.

Require Suggestions.
Thanks

Comment: Brother have try something?

Comment: Ya tried with NSSort Descriptor and NSPredicate

Comment: can we show code for this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `sortUsingComparator` for sort array,

1 - Create model class.
2 - Convert dictionary to model and add array.
3 - sort array

.h
@interface DOBModel : NSObject

```
@property NSString *name;
@property NSString *dob;// change NSString to NSDate in your code

@end
```

.......

```
 DOBModel *model=[[DOBModel alloc]init];
    model.name=@"123";
    model.dob=@"01-01-2014";
    [array addObject:model];
    model=[[DOBModel alloc]init];
    model.name=@"023";
    model.dob=@"01-01-2014";
    [array addObject:model];
    model=[[DOBModel alloc]init];
    model.name=@"12";
    model.dob=@"01-01-2014";
    [array addObject:model];
    NSLog(@"%@",array);
    [array sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
        return [((DOBModel *)obj1).name compare:((DOBModel *)obj2).name];
    }];

    NSLog(@"%@",array);
```